# Would a list of acronyms be a good CW? Or meta question?

Tags: discussion, beta

There are a lot of acronyms that are used a lot around here, for example PIE, NLP, ASL and possibly others. As our site is entering public beta soon, the meaning of these acronyms might not be so obvious for them... Would it be a good idea to create a page, maybe a CW or a meta question, to list these acronyms and their meanings?

Comment: Good question. I don't know which one is the best choice, but I think we should make a "database" with all those acronyms.

Answer (score 2):

No.  There are references like Wikipedia for things like that.  This is a website about linguistics, so some level of familiarity with the terminology is prerequisite for using it.

Comment: I don't agree. I mean, there might be cases where you don't know an acronym, for a variety of reasons. For example, the SE sites are not only for experts, besides also experts might not know 100% of the acronyms (especially if just made up). Besides, also the EL&U has made such [a meta post](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/147/list-of-common-abbreviations-noad-esl-pie), for example.

Comment: @Alenanno: I personally like the existence of the ELU meta post and would like it here too. But I'd like to point out that that post is not particularly accessible. You have to realize that the page exists and then use the stackexchange search feature to find it (as opposed to the FAQ which is an immediate link).

Comment: Speaking from experience, Wikipedia rarely has the more "arcane" linguistics acronyms which might come up only in certain theoretical frameworks or subfields. It would also be handy to have a linguistics glossary all in one place...